# a lingering fragrance

Tags: phrase-usage

Is the phrase "a lingering fragrance" okay in English? Should it be "lingering fragrances"?

A Chinese student wrote this sentence:

> If you present a bunch of roses as a gift to a person, there will be **a lingering fragrance** in your hands.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you may be asking about a translation of [this Chinese adage](https://forum.wordreference.com/threads/%E4%BA%88%E4%BA%BA%E7%8E%AB%E7%91%B0%EF%BC%8C%E6%89%8B%E6%9C%89%E4%BD%99%E9%A6%99.2100534/).

Although "fragrance" is both a count and noncount noun, it is better to use it uncountably here.

"*In* your hands" sounds odd to me. I would say

> Your hand retains/will retain a lingering note of fragrance.

Answer (score 2):

"a lingering fragrance" is correct, but it should be "on your hands" instead of "in your hands".

Answer (score 1):

A fragrance is "a pleasant, sweet smell." (Oxford languages).  A bunch of roses has a fragrance so the singular is correct and natural.

I'm not sure about "in your hands".  Do they mean that your hands will pick up the scent of the roses?